# VBA expected end of statement

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I am trying to edit my excel table with VBA but an error appears while compiling. It doesnt recognize line 2 and line 10.

```
Sub IfThenElse()
    Dim i As Integer = 23
    While Not IsNull(Cells(i, 35).Value)
        If Cells(i, 35).Value > 1E+16 Then
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 35).Value / 10
        Else
            Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 35).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement

Comment: A `For ... Next` loop would probably be better here. `IsNull(Cells(i, 35).Value)` - this doesn't do what you think it does. `IsEmpty` perhaps instead of `IsNull`.

Comment: `Dim i As Integer = 23` is also not valid syntax. Declare, then assign value.

Comment: This `While` … `End While` is no valid syntax, you need to use `Do While` … `Loop` (see [Do...Loop statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)).

Comment: Or [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and use a `For` ... `Next` loop.

Comment: @BigBen Just for the record "Last used cell" is not the same as "first blank cell" (what the OP does right now). So the outcome may be different.

Answer (score 3):

1. You cannot declare a variable and set a value at the same time `Dim i As Integer = 23`
2. Row counts are of type `Long` not `Integer`, Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

   ```
   Dim i As Long 
   i = 23
   ```
3. `While` … `End While` is no valid syntax, you need to use `Do While` … `Loop` (see [Do...Loop statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)).
4. It is very unlikely that a cell value is `Null` if you are looking for an empty cell use `IsEmpty` or check for `vbNullString`

   ```
   Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 35).Value) 'or Do While Not Cells(i, 35).Value = vbNullString
       If Cells(i, 35).Value > 1E+16 Then
           Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 35).Value / 10
       Else
           Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 35).Value
           i = i + 1
       End If
   Loop
   ```
5. Not sure what exactly you are doing but `i = i + 1` might need to come after `End If`.

Comment: The VBA syntax for while is while/wend. However the use of this structure is deprecated in favour of the more flexible do loop construct. Also, when reading up on VBA do make sure that you haven't mistakenly landed on a Visual Basic (VB net) page

Comment: @freeflow That's why I suggested the `Do` loop.

Comment: @peh The way you explained wasn't very clear imho